# Fit a wrapfigure to content

Tags: wrapfigure

When defining a wrapfigure (or a minipage), I need to specify the width of the figure. Is there a possibility that this width is determined by the picture inside?

For sake of an MWE, I'll use a tikzpicture. I **don't** want to chage the scale of the image since my image is used multiple times in the document, but in different variations and it should have the same scale all the time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0)circle (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{A circle}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This looks bad:
[image: first attempt]

Adding `\centering` improves a bit, but then I still have too much spacing left and right.

I want to have an output like this:

[image: good output]

(This was created using `4cm` as width, but I **don't** want to guess the size of the image - easy for the circle, harder if you have a more complicated image)

To  sum it up, is there an option to fit the width of a wrapfigure (or any environment, like a minipage) to an image without rescaling the image and without guessing the size?

Edit: Not a duplicate of [Do I really have to specify the width of my wrapfigure twice?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178633), since in this case the author *knows* the width of the image and therefore can specify it, I don't.

Comment: Have you had a look at the possible duplicate?

Comment: I had, and edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\begin{document}
\sbox{0}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0)circle (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{\wd0}
    \centering
     \usebox{0}%
    \captionof{figure}{A circle}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really like this since it works for more than wrapfigures.

Comment: +1 -- although the `wrapfig` manual suggestion is very convenient, it does have a recognized downside, which this doesn't.  (at least not the same one.)  and the `caption` package nicely wraps and centers the caption if it's wider than the drawing; looks a bit funny if a line is very short, but it's automatic.

Comment: Is the box essential? I somehow get the feeling the box is really needed in this example, but is it?

Comment: @OlegLobachev  you need a box to put the content in so you can measure it

Answer (score 7):

this is addressed in section 2 of the `wrapfig` documentation, where it says

> if you specify a width of zero (0pt), the actual width of the figure
>   will determine the wrapping width. A following `\caption` should have
>   the same width as the figure, but it might fail badly; it is safer to
>   specify a width when you use a caption.

advice: rtfm.

Comment: Great, but I do use captions. I might give it a shot though.